# java:14: error: missing return statement }

Tags: java, return

I've been learning Java for two weeks and I'm stuck on this exercise. This might be a very simple question but I couldn't find the problem yet. I'm trying to test the first method I've written in this algorithme :

```
 1 import java.util.*;
 2 public class stationnement {
 3                  public static void main (String[] args) {
 4                  int j = jour();
 5                  System.out.println(j);
 6         }
 7         public static int jour() {
 8                 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 9                 System.out.println("Rentrez le jour");
10                 int x = sc.nextInt(); 
11                 if (x > 0 && x <=31){return x;}
12         }       
13         
14 }
```

When I compile my code I get *stationnement.java:12: error: missing return statement
    }*,
even though I put the return x after the condition. I tried deleting the if condition and it worked. But I would like to know what's the problem here. Isn't correct to place the condition there?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Hi Juanloz... please make sure to check for similar questions before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You have to always return a value, (or throw an error) You can't return a value sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

your method `public static int jour() ......` expects a return statement

your are returning the value on the `if` part  `if (x > 0 && x <=31){return x;}`

you should also return a value when `if` condition fails

change your code something like the below

```
 if (x > 0 && x <=31){return x;}
else{return 0;// I am returning 0 when if condtion fails}
```

Comment: I completed it with an else return 0; and it worked. Next time, I'll read more before asking silly questions.  Thank you Spring !

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement you have provided is inside the `if` block which means the return statement wouldn't be executed or reached if the condition is false.
You must provide a return statement outside the `if` statement which will be used even if the condition is false.The function must return something since its not `void`.But in this case,it doesn't if the condition is not satisfied.You will have to use an 'else' block and return 0.